# Where do I find Bigcommerce store hash value

Tags: bigcommerce, custom-fields

I want to use the Bigcommerce API from [here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/custom_fields#get-product-custom-field).

I need a custom field so I will use

`GET /stores/{store_hash}/v2/products/{product_id}/custom_fields/{id}`.

Where do I find the `{store_hash}` value?

Answer (score 4):

Go to ***Advanced Settings -> Api Accounts*** then click ***Create API Account***, you'll find it in the ***API PATH*** field `https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{{store-hash}}/v3/

Answer (score 2):

The Bigcommerce store hash value can also be derived from your temp URL. For example, if your temp URL is *http ://store-xxxxxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/* then your *store_hash* value is the *xxxxxxxxx*.
[bigcommerce](/questions/tagged/bigcommerce)

Comment: I cannot see such a url after login. From where we will get it ?

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, then you can find it in the page source, for example:

view-source:https://xxxxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/manage/settings/auth/api-accounts

where xxxxxxxx is your store's URL prefix.

Search for "store_hash" or "storeHash" from the page source

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:** BigCommerce Store Hash by Login store

1. log in to your [BigCommerce Account & open a store](https://login.bigcommerce.com/).
2. Check the URL after login the store, and you will see URL like this:
   https://store-**xvd512155**.mybigcommerce.com
   **xvd512155** is the store hash
   [image]

**Method 2:** BigCommerce Store Hash from API Account

1. log in to your [BigCommerce Account & open a store](https://login.bigcommerce.com/).
2. Go to **Advanced Settings > API Accounts**
3. Click the **Create API Account** button
   You will receive an API path like this:
   https://api.bigcommerce.com/ stores/**xvd512155**/v3/
   **xvd512155** is the store hash of your BigCommerce store.

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here i found my answer: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/legacy/basic-auth

Enabling API Access => you login and in the json returned you will find store_auth

Comment: the store hash isn't required for the legacy api / basic auth

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: More recent link: [Receiving the GET Request](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#receiving-the-get-request)